# Creating an arguments and adding it to a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm pretty new to javascript looking for some help on creating an argument and adding it to a click event in jquery

Heres a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/8VwAy/1/

Can someone help example what I have to do?

Thanks

Comment: seems like you already posted today under a different user name ;-)

Comment: @EvilP Can you find that question, and mark this question as a dupe?

Comment: Yeah I have looked it up but didn't find the question, but it was the exact same code from the fiddle.

Comment: PS. @user Your current code is pure JavaScript. I strongly recommend to not use jQuery until you know JavaScript very well. When you learn jQuery and JavaScript together, you will **never** easily get a full understanding of JavaScript, because your knowledge is polluted by jQuery's syntax and rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Do not use `arguments` as a variable name, since every function already defines the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object.

Your code does not work, because you have injected the JavaScript through the `onload` setting in JSFiddle. This runs code after the document has loaded.
In the body section, you're calling a function which is not defined yet.

**What happens?**
Definition:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Defines window.demo.Alert...
}; ...
window.demo.Alert();
```

Calling order:

```
window.demo.Alert(); // Error: 'demo' is not defined.
window.onload = ...
```

Change `onload` to `nowrap (head)` to get your code to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8VwAy/7/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass data to the event handler as the first parameter

```
            $(".js-link").click("myne", function(e) {
                alert(e.data);
                alert("Hello world");
            });
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8VwAy/8/